# Using MTOM on Mono

Tags: .net, web-services, mono, mtom

Looking to port an ASMX web service application to run on Mono under Apache.  The web services use WSE 3.0 to add MTOM capability for messages that contain binary.  From my research so far, I understand this to be the current state of web services on Mono:

1. ASMX is fully implemented (but does not support MTOM)
2. WSE (which I am using for MTOM support on .NET) is not supported
3. WCF is not yet implemented on Mono to a sufficient extent to create web service applications.

It seems that my best way forward would be to try and implement MTOM myself on top of the existing ASMX support.  Does anyone have any better ideas or know of 3rd party support for something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is open source world. If anything is not there, you can feel free to add it (you can decide whether to share the work with others).

Mono team already started to work on WCF (HTTP basic binding). I think they will invest more here as more and more people move to WCF.